# Debug a PHPUnit test with xdebug using DBGP Proxy

Tags: phpunit, xdebug, phpstorm

We use DBGP Proxy for making xdebug works with multiple hosts.

To debug a page, i create a run/debug configuration (PHP Web Application) and add the **XDEBUG_SESSION_START=mykey** to the start URL like this:

[image: PHP Web Application]

Then i push the Run button (if i push Debug button, PHPStorm will add an other XDEBUG_SESSION_START with a random value), and it works.

Now, i want to debug some PHPUnit test so I've created a "PHPUnit on Server" configurations.
The test is launched correctly, but i can't debug it. When i launch a debug, PHPStorm generate a key for the Xdebug session, and don't use 'mykey'.

**How can i force PHPStorm to set the XDEBUG_SESSION_START with the value i want?**

I try to create a PHP Remote Debug like this:

[image: Remote Debug]

Once launched, i run the test, but PHPStorm launch a new Xdebug session with a random id...

Comment: Have not done any "PHPUnit on Server" myself (ever, only local), but I think you can use approach described here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm  (in short: activate debug listener in PhpStorm .. and then activate actual debug session manually when required via bookmarklet or browser extension (or by adding XDEBUG_SESSION_START manually to the url)

Comment: Debug in browser works fine, the problem comes from PHPUnit test. I can't add the XDEBUG_SESSION_START to a PHPUnit url. I don't access them with a browser, so the bookmarklet solution isn't possible.

Comment: When using "PHPUnit" Run/Debug Configuration, the tests got executed in local CLI environment. When using "PHPUnit on Server" .. it is done over **web interface** (by calling URL with some parameters) -- you *should be* able to add your own parameter there. Maybe you are facing the basic issue that "PHPUNit on Server" simply does not work at all (I mean: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9369 ) ?? Other than that -- no useful ideas.